# Alguém sabe informar por que esse código Lazarus/Pascal dá erro?

Tags: lazarus

É uma classe simples com métodos get e set, mas gera um erro ao invocar qualquer uma das funções ou procedures (de início achei que essa só na linha 43).

```
unit uPais;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, Dialogs;

type
  Pais = class
    private
      codigo:integer;
      descricao:string;
    public
      constructor Create; // construtor
      destructor  Destroy; // destrutor
      // Setters
      procedure setCodigo(pCodigo:integer);
      procedure setDescricao(pDescricao:string);
      // Getters
      function getCodigo():integer;
      function getDescricao():string;

  end;// fim da classe

implementation
constructor Pais.Create();
begin
  codigo := 0;
  descricao := '';
end;

destructor Pais.Destroy();
begin
  //Freemem(@codigo);
  //Freemem(@descricao);
end;

// Setters
procedure Pais.setCodigo(pCodigo:integer);
begin
  codigo := pCodigo;
end;

procedure Pais.setDescricao(pDescricao:string);
begin
  descricao := pDescricao;
end;

// Getters
function Pais.getCodigo():integer;
begin
  Result := codigo;
end;

function Pais.getDescricao():string;
begin
  Result := descricao;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Acho que você poderia colocar no enunciado qual foi o erro exibido.

Comment: Nenhum erro foi exibido, o Lazarus apenas gera um erro aponta um erro nas linhas em que tento fazer as atribuições ex:  (codigo := pcodigo)

Answer (score 0):

No Object Pascal, o correto é usar `property`, assim:

```
unit uPais;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses Classes, SysUtils, Dialogs;

type
    Pais = class
    private
      fCodigo: Integer; // por convenção insira um "f" antes do nome do campo
      fDescricao: string;

      procedure SetCodigo(Value: Integer);
      procedure SetDescricao(Value: string);
    public
        constructor Create; // construtor
        destructor  Destroy; // destrutor

        property Codigo Integer read fCodigo write SetCodigo;
        property Descricao string read fDescricao write SetDescricao;

    end;// fim da classe

implementation

constructor Pais.Create;
begin
    fCodigo    := 0;
    fDescricao := '';
end;

destructor Pais.Destroy;
begin
    //Freemem(@codigo);
    //Freemem(@descricao);
end;

// Setters
procedure Pais.SetCodigo(Value: Integer);
begin
    fCodigo := Value;
end;

procedure Pais.SetDescricao(Value: string);
begin
    fDescricao := Value;
end;

end.
```

Se desejar, crie os *getters* da mesma forma.